# How To Simplify This Code In Wordpress Function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm Trying to make a function, my code works but i wonder is there any way to simplify my code? with loop maybe?

Background:

I try to show data from usermeta (the usermeta from plugin)
so these are the meta key:

- child_name
- child_name_1
- child_name_2
- child_name_3

and so on.. based on how much user input their children in database.

example, if user only input 2 children, meta key will be:

- child_name
- child_name_1

temporary, i limit only 3 children to input, because i can't simplify it.

```
function get_child_name(){

$user = wp_get_current_user();
$count_extra_field = $user->wppb_repeater_field_15_extra_groups_count;
$count_child = $count_extra_field + 1;


$child_name_0 = $user->child_name;
$child_name_1 = $user->child_name_1;
$child_name_2 = $user->child_name_2;

$child_names = array($child_name_0,$child_name_1,$child_name_2);

$n=0;
foreach($child_names as $child_name) {
if($n==$count_child) break;
$n++;
echo $child_name;
}
}
add_shortcode('child_names', 'get_child_name');
```

Above code is works, as I use it now.
but is it possible to simplify it / automate the process?
So, user can input as many children as possible.
or if I want to increase the limit (for input children names) I don't have to add the code again manually, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to simplify the code. Meta fields are being created dynamically based on index. Please check code below. With this you dont have to touch this function again when you want to increase the number of fields.

```
function get_child_name(){

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    $count_extra_field = $user->wppb_repeater_field_15_extra_groups_count;

    $names = array();

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $count_extra_field; $i++ ) {
        $meta_key = 'child_name';
        $key_suffix = ( 0 === $i ) ? '' : '_' . $i ;
        $meta_key .= $key_suffix;

        if ( $user->$meta_key ) {
            $names[] = $user->$meta_key;
        }
    }

    if ( ! empty( $names ) ) {
        foreach ( $names as $name ) {
            echo $name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that $count_extra_field is the count of additional number of fields added by the user, because the default field for children is: 1. that's why i use $count_child = $count_extra_field + 1; But your code works perfectly and i choose it as the answer. Thank you